# Main storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

When I'm sending data from "firstViewController" to secondViewController", on the second screen my data looking like this:
[image]
Why it's like this?

My code is:

```
if (_index == 0) {
        recipes = @[@"Польза поминания"];
    }
    else if (_index == 1) {
        recipes = @[@"", @"Об этикете и условиях обращения с мольбами к Аллаху"];
    }
    else if (_index == 2) {
        recipes = @[@"",@"", @"Почему мы иногда не получаем ответа на свои мольбы?"];
    }
    else if (_index == 3) {
        recipes = @[@"", @"",@"", @"1 СЛОВА ПОМИНАНИЯ ПРИ ПРОБУЖДЕНИИ ОТО СНА.", @"2 СЛОВА ПОМИНАНИЯ ПРИ ПРОБУЖДЕНИИ ОТО СНА.", @"3 СЛОВА ПОМИНАНИЯ ПРИ ПРОБУЖДЕНИИ ОТО СНА.", @"4 СЛОВА ПОМИНАНИЯ ПРИ ПРОБУЖДЕНИИ ОТО СНА."];
    }
```

If i put it without @"", @"". It can't send correct data to "3rdViewController"

Comment: How is that suppose to be? How do you pass "index" (I guess?) Where do you pass data, how do you pass data ?

Comment: Please post your second view controller's data source code.

Comment: You need a better data structure for your tables.  Exactly what is impossible to tell from the question, but '*without @"", @"". It can't send correct data to "3rdViewController*"' is proof that there's something really wrong.